# Reactjs - axios post request isn't working - 404 not found

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

went through some answers regarding this issue but couldn't solve it.

The Axios call doesn't recognize the PHP URL.
it returns 404
this is my action creator:

```
import {
    GET_ALL_LECTURERS
} from './consts'
import axios from "axios";
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api';


export const getAllLecturers = () => {
    let url = `${baseUrl}/lec.php`;

    return dispatch => {
        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                dispatch({ type: GET_ALL_LECTURERS, value: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
};
```

Here is the file location image.
[image]

What I am missing?

Comment: Your React app works in dev server. PHP will not work in that server, PHP should be hosted in a server that support php files (eg: Apache server)

Comment: the entire folder sits in `D:\xampp\htdocs\react\achvagen\api\`
If I call the file directly using `127.0.0.1\react\achvagen\api\lec.php` I can see its output

Comment: I didnt solved the problem but I managed to wok using this url 

`const baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/react/achvagen/api';`

Comment: Which means your baseUrl was incorrect, it should be `http://localhost/react/achvagen/api` or `http://127.0.0.1/react/achvagen/api` as you provided